# Is it possible to know what triggers would fire given a query?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a database with (too) many triggers. They can cascade.

I have a query, which seems simple, and by no means I can remember the effect of all triggers. So, that simple query might actually be not simple at all and not do what I expect.

Is there a way to know what triggers would fire before running the query, or what triggers have fired after running it (not committed yet)?

I am not really interested in queries like `SELECT … FROM user_triggers WHERE …` because I know them already, and also because it does not tell me whether the firing conditions of the triggers will be met in my query.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know a way of simulating trigger execution but if you are able to alter the triggers bodies you might wanna add some log statements like an insert into a dedicated table with its name and a timestamp.
By the way: If you're using 11g you shuld take a look at compound triggers ...

Comment: @Toby, adding log statements would be an idea… but it would mean rewriting them all. Will look at compound triggers but we have customers using still 9i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I have a database with (too) many triggers. They can cascade."

This is just one of the reasons why many people anathematize triggers.

> "Is there a way to know what triggers would fire before running the
>   query"

No.  Let's consider something which you might find in an UPDATE trigger body:

```
if :new.sal > :old.sal * 1.2 then
    insert into big_pay_rises values (:new.empno, :old.sal, :new.sal, sysdate);
end if;
```

How could we tell whether the trigger on BIG_PAY_RISES will fire?  It might, it might not depending on an algorithm we cannot parse out of the DML statement.

So, the best you can hope for is a recursive search of DBA_TRIGGERS and DBA_DEPENDENCIES to identify all the triggers which *might* feature in your cascade.  But it's going to be impossible to identify which ones will definitely fire in any given scenario.

> " or what triggers have fired after running it (not committed yet)?"

As others have pointed out, logging is one option.  But if  you are using Oracle 11g you have another option: the PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler.  This is a non-intrusive tool which tracks all the PL/SQL program units touched by a PL/SQL call, *including triggers*.  One of the cool features of the Hierarchical Profiler is that it includes PUs which belong in other schemas, which might be useful with cascading triggers.

So, you just need to wrap your SQL in an anonymous block and call it with the Hierarchical Profiler.  Then you can filter you report to reveal only the triggers which fired.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm) .

Comment: So that's exactly what I wanted, thanks. I suppose with 10g we're stuck with plain old logs then, but some of our test databases are 11g.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to know what triggers would fire before running the query, **or what triggers have fired after running it (not committed yet)**?

To address this I would run the query inside an anonymous block using a PL/SQL debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing called parse through your query and give u the triggers involved in your query. It is going to be as simple as this. Just pick the table names from the query you are running and for each one just list the triggers using the following query before running the query. Isn't that simple enough?

```
select  trigger_name
,   trigger_type
,   status
from    dba_triggers
where   owner = '&owner'
and table_name = '&table'
order by status, trigger_name
```

Comment: Not that simple, I'm afraid. It's recursive -- you update table A, which fires an on-update-row trigger that inserts a record into table B (and maybe 3 other tables, with 2 more changed on the statement trigger). Those fire triggers that do something to table C. And so forth. You could get closer by tracing through the dependencies, at least to a set of all possible triggers that might be affected. But not just the ones that would actually fire.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying, the query I gave is for just one table and not for all of them